# Find all naturals $n>1$, such that the value of the sum $2^2 +3^2 +4^2 +\cdots+n^2$ equals $p^k$ where $p$ is a prime and $k$ is natural

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I simplified the sum using the formula of the sum of the squares

$$\frac{(n-1)(2 n^2 + 5n+6)}{6}=p^k$$

Moreover $\gcd(n-1,2n^2+5n+6)=1$ or $13$

I need help to complete the solution.

Comment: Please format your questions with MathJax for better readability. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The $n=2,3,4,7$ giving $p^k=2^2,13^1,29^1,139^1$ are only solutions for $n\le10^6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us restrict (as in the OP) a possible common divisor of the factors $f(n)=(n-1)$, and $g(n)=(2n^2+5n+6)$. Such a divisor $d$ further divides the rest after division with rest of $g(n)=(2n^2+5n+6)$ by $(n-1)$, which is the value of $g$ in $1$, $g(1)=2+5+6=13$. Note that $13$ is relatively prime to $6=2\cdot 3$, so that after a simplification with $2$ and $3$ of the factors in the numerator, the simplified factors can still only have $1$ or $13$ as a gcd.

Now we split the situation into cases.

- The case $n=6k$. We have see if the following expression may be a prime power:
  $$(12k^2 + 5k + 1)(6k - 1)\ .$$
  Assume the result is a prime $p$ power. The two factors are both $>1$, so they must be powers of $p$. So $p=13$, and the smaller factor must be $13$. (A power of $13$ is also excluded, since then $13^2$ would be a common divisor.) Contradiction.
- The case $n=6k+1$. We have see if the following expression may be a prime power:
  $$(72k^2 + 54k + 13)k\ .$$
  Assume the result is a prime $p$ power. 
  The case $k=1$ leads to a solution, $\color{red}{n=7}$, since $72+54+13=139$ is a prime.

Consider further the case $k>1$.
The two factors are then both $>1$, so they must be powers of $p$. So $p=13$, and the smaller factor must be $13$. (A power of $13$ is again excluded...) The value $k=13$ does not lead to a solution, the first factor being $13\cdot 991$. Contradiction.

- The case $n=6k+2$. We have see if the following expression may be a prime power:
  $$(12k^2 + 13k + 4)(6k + 1)\ .$$
  Assume the result is a prime $p$ power. 
  The case $k=0$ does not leads to a solution, so $\color{red}{n=2}$ is this solution.

Assume now $k>0$.
The two factors are then both $>1$, so they must be powers of $p$. So $p=13$, and the smaller factor must be $13$. (A power of $13$ is again excluded.) This happens only for $k=1$, but the first factor $12+13+4$ is not a power of $13$. Contradiction.

- The case $n=6k+3$. We have see if the following expression may be a prime power:
  $$(24k^2 + 34k + 13)(3k + 1)\ .$$
  Assume the result is a prime $p$ power. 
  The case $k=0$ gives a solution, so $\color{red}{n=3}$. The other factor is the prime $13$.

Assume now that $k>0$. The two factors are then both $>1$, so they must be powers of $p$. So $p=13$, and the smaller factor must be $13$. (A power of $13$ is again excluded.) The value $k=4$ does not lead to a solution, the first factor being $533=13\cdot 41$. No other solution could be found.

- The case $n=6k+4$. We have see if the following expression may be a prime power:
  $$(36k^2 + 63k + 29)(2k + 1)\ .$$
  Assume the result is a prime $p$ power. 
  The case $k=0$ gives a solution, so $\color{red}{n=4}$. The other factor is the prime $29$.

Assume now that $k>0$. The two factors are then both $>1$, so they must be powers of $p$. So $p=13$, and the smaller factor must be $13$. (A power of $13$ is again excluded.) The value $k=6$ does not lead to a solution, the first factor being $1703=13\cdot 131$. No other solution could be found.

- The case $n=6k+5$. We have see if the following expression may be a prime power:
  $$(24k^2 + 50k + 27)(3k + 2)\ .$$
  Assume the result is a prime $p$ power. 
  The two factors are then both $>1$, so they must be powers of $p$. So $p=13$, and the smaller factor must be $13$. (A power of $13$ is again excluded.) This is not possible. No solution in this branch.

---

Computer check, searching for values for $n$ from $2$ to $1000$.

```
sage: for n in [2..1000]:
....:     S = ZZ( n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 - 1 )
....:     if S.is_prime_power():
....:         print "n=%s sum = %s = %s" % (n, S, S.factor())
....:         
....:         
n=2 sum = 4 = 2^2
n=3 sum = 13 = 13
n=4 sum = 29 = 29
n=7 sum = 139 = 139
```

Answer (score 1):

You have done most of the work. If the gcd is 1, then $n-1$ must be 1,2,3 or 6. It is easy to check that $n=2,3,4,7$ are solutions (giving $k=2,p=2$ and $k=1$ and $p=13,29,139$).

Otherwise, we must have $p=13$ and $k>1$. We cannot have $13^2|n-1$, because if $13^2|2n^2+5n+6$, then $13$ is not the gcd, so $2n^2+5n+6<6\cdot13<13^2=n-1$, which is clearly false. So $n=13+1,2\cdot13+1,3\cdot13+1$ or $6\cdot13+1$. It is easy to check that none of these values work.

**Case 1**. $n=13+1$. We must have $2n^2+5n+6=6\cdot13^m$, so $$2\cdot13^2+9\cdot13+13=6\cdot13^m$$ which is impossible (any number has a unique representation base 13. So it is not a solution.

**Case 2**. $n=2\cdot13+1$. We must have $2n^2+5n+6=3\cdot13^m$, so $$8\cdot13^2+13^2+5\cdot13+13=3\cdot13^m\text{ or }9\cdot13^2+6\cdot13=3\cdot13^m$$ That is again impossible for the same reason.

**Case 3**. $n=3\cdot13+1$. In a similar way we get $$13^3+5\cdot13^2+2\cdot13^2+13^1+13=3\cdot13^m$$ which is again impossible.

**Case 4**. $n=6\cdot13+1$. In a similar way we get $$5\cdot13^3+7\cdot13^2+4\cdot13^2+3\cdot13=6\cdot13^m$$ which is again impossible.